# How to get unity build dependencies after apply the LTS Enablement Stacks?

Tags: unity, apt, compiling, dependencies, lts

I have a Ubuntu 14.04.2 installation with the **LTS Enablement Stacks** (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack).

I would like to build the **Unity** package from source to apply some custom patches.

When I try to install the build dependecies I have unmet dependecies:

```
$ sudo apt-get build-dep unity
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 xserver-xorg-video-dummy : Depends: xorg-video-abi-15
                            Depends: xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.14.99.902)
E: Build-dependencies for unity could not be satisfied.
```

Note that I do not have the `xserver-xorg-core` because the LTS Enablement Stacks replaces it to the `xserver-xorg-core-lts-utopic package.`

How I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved that problem by installing `xserver-xorg-dev` package.

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-dev
```